# ASP.NET MVC Registration create Claim on E-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I am new to MVC , and I would need help with creating a claim on email.
I am using ASP.NET web application MVC (Visual studio 2013/Framework 5.1).
My goal is to extend existing ApplicationUser model. I added [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string Email { get; set; } 
and created a registration model with same , updated the view so i can type in my email but I don't know how to claim it so it will be unique in database and show message like it does for username.

Answer (score 0):

- Asp.net Identity uses entity framework code first model framework by which you can generate/scaffold custom code through entity framework migrations like , Add-Migration Init, Update Database packages, which gives you add your custom code to entity framework default data model for Asp.net Identity framework.

In your case, you want to use *Email* instead *UserName* which is quite logical.

Please go through [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun), though i am giving you some quick steps along with some code for your reference.

- Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations - Adds *Migrations* folder in your project along with *Configuration.cs* which bootstraps automatic migrations for your db context.
- Add-Migrations Init - This gives you new code files to customize table/properties for *DbMigration* class which is partial by default. It will give you two overrides *Up()* and *Down()*.  For email change, here is the file which will look like below after change.

  ```
  public override void Up()
  {
      AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserName", c => c.String());
  }    
  public override void Down()
  {
      AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserName", c => c.String());
  }
  ```
- Once you are done with this, you need to fire *Update Database* package from library package manager.

If everything goes well, *ApplicationUser* with updated dbcontext/database properties will be available to application.